# How does my loop know to iterate through a list if i didnt use range(len(<list>))

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is a small project for class:

```
# Three different lists

hairstyles = ["bouffant", "pixie", "dreadlocks", "crew", "bowl", "bob", "mohawk", "flattop"]

prices = [30, 25, 40, 20, 20, 35, 50, 35]

last_week = [2, 3, 5, 8, 4, 4, 6, 2]


new_prices = [price - 5 for price in prices]
print(str(new_prices)) #prints 25, 20, 35, 15, 15, 30, 45, 30

total_revenue = 0

for i in range(len(hairstyles)):
  total_revenue += prices[i] * last_week[i]

print("Total Revenue: " + str(total_revenue))


cuts_under_30 = [hairstyles[i] for i in range(len(hairstyles)) if new_prices[i] < 30]
print(str(cuts_under_30))
```

I'm confused as to how my loop knows to iterate through every index in `new_prices[I]` without using `range(len(new_prices))`or in`total_revenue += prices[i] * last_week[I]`. Would I not need to use `range(len())` to iterate through the list?

My project printed out correct and I passed my project. I'm more so asking for future reference and a learning experience on loops

Comment: Well, all of your lists have 8 items, so len(prices)=len(hairstyles)=len(last_week). So I goes from 0 to 7 and cycles through all your items in every list. If you make shorten e.g. list prices, it would not work anymore and you come up with an error message. Was that your question?

Comment: _I'm confused as to how my loop knows to iterate through every index in `new_prices[I]`_ What loop are you talking about?  I only see two `for` loops here, and they both refer to `range(len(hairstyles))`.  I don't see anything that would loop over `new_prices`...

Comment: @destructioneer yes that was my question, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: the first for loop goes through all eight items in prices. for each item in prices a new item in new_prices will be appended. so all lists in there are of the same length and your independen integer variable i goes from beginning to the end through all items in every list you have.

Comment: @destructioneer that makes a lot of sense, thanks for being helpful

Comment: And `total_revenue` could be calculated like this: `total_revenue = sum(price * count for price, count in zip(prices, last_week))`

Answer (score 1):

No, you dont always have to use  `range(len(new_prices))`   to iterate through a list. In your code below, you used list comprehension that iterates through each price in new_prices.

```
new_prices = [price - 5 for price in prices]
```

Answer (score 0):

In first case, the for loop iterator 'price' directly points to the value in the list by iterating from 0 to len-1
Where as in second case the loop iterator 'i' points to the index of the list
But second one you can write it in alternate way as :

```
cuts_under_30 = [hairstyle for hairstyle in hairstyles if hairstyle < 30]
```

This will return the same output. In this the iterator 'hairstyle' points to the value in the 'hairstyles' list